# Spring Message Source is using deleted keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, message

we are using messagesource to pull error messages from a properties file via method:
messageSource.getMessage("error", options, locale)

Now, when I change or delete the key "error" in hotswap, the message is NOT changed.

I don't understand why deleting or changing this key has no effect on the server.  Could it be saved to the database on server startup?

Comment: That is a interesting question. Can hotswap also changes .properties files?

Comment: Is debugging an option?

Comment: Yes, I get into pretty low level java and I can see that "cache" starts getting used.

Comment: That's a good question @Arashsoft, but I am manually changing the contents of the properties file.  If I change the key in java, the change is reflected upon save.  I do not see a good reason for hot swap not affecting properties files also.  Especially because messagesource pulls information from properties files upon request, so the values and keys can be altered at anytime and be reflected immediately.

Comment: Maybe the server is keeping your first properties file, and thus not loading your new one. If you change the file, and redeploy the server, it keeps with the wrong message?